# Create gwt module in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gwt

I watched the [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QJR1Zw9j-rk) which is showing how to create GWT lib in NetBeans... I tried to find some examples of particular tutorial of how to create GWT module but with Eclipse. I couldn't find any. It seems to be quite specific or something information :(

So my question is how to create GWT module with Eclipse (to have, as a result, gwt projects importable lib jar)?

P.S>
GWT 2.3

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you want to use the Maven, you can create a new Maven module from some GWT archetype.
- If you are not familiar with Maven, you can install the [GWT plugin](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/usingeclipse) and then create new gwt module via Eclipse new project wizard.
- Another option is to use [webAppCreator](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/RefCommandLineTools#webAppCreator) script which is part of GWT from command line.

Comment: (according to step B) I tried creating new GWT module with eclipse but it requires a pre-created src folder :( I am not sure what src folder is expected... Should it be a GWT project src folder or GWT lib src folder or...? So there should be created something more before creating GWT module itself? I have GWT 2.3 installed

Comment: ... I have installed GWT plugin. I want to create importable lib so I am not sure where should I start? Should I create gwt project first and then create lib based on the project? What are the optimal basic steps for eclipse?

Comment: Strange, I am able to create it with the Eclipse wizard. _File -> New -> Project... -> Google -> Web App Proj. -> Next -- here you have to set up the GWT SDK, project name and package -- -> Finish_

that's it

Comment: So you create GWT module based on Web App Proj? OK... So how then do you export the project as re-usable lib jar with eclipse ide?

Comment: Depends on what you want. Do you want to have some business core logic separated in standalone jar file and use it from your GWT app? Or to have some standalone GWT component which can be reused from other GWT app?

If the former is the case, you'll make a common java project, do whatever you want and reuse it from GWT (no rocket science)

The latter needs you to provide the source code together with the compiled classes in the resulting jar file. And in the GWT app's descriptor (which is going to include the other jar) you have to place the `<inherits name="com.your.package.FancyComponent"/>`

Comment: No, afaik. The source code for UI is compulsory, because the generated javascript is not part of the module jar and the permutation for particular browser and locale is generated during the compile time.

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5/wiki/DevGuideArchivingGWTModules it's old, but still valid

Comment: Emm... I want to ask about the link... it says "1. Create a new JAR file that contains the module you wish to archive, including all source code for the module (including Module XML file and public resources). " ... what it means concerning the 'public resources' is it a gwt library 'src/public' folder or what?

Comment: It will be easier to see an example of the final product here (http://code.google.com/p/gwt-log/downloads/detail?name=gwt-log-3.1.8.jar). As you may see, inside the jar file there are all public sources (images, static html pages, icons, etc.), GWT module descriptors (*.gwt.xml) and finally in the particular directory structure according to the package there are build classes *.class together with their uncompiled source code *.java.

Comment: It is easy to achieve this structure with maven, you'll add the "resources" goal (example from one of my projects: http://goo.gl/OM1yU)